# changing image's size to fit the new size of the GUI window

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qt5.2

I've read the documentation of Qt for resizing policy but I couldn't find how can I achieve the scenario of changing the image's size to fit the new size of Qlabel.

This is my GUI structure

```
mainLayout:
    toplayout:
        QLabel
        QPushButton
```

Now I have `cv::Mat` image. I have converted to `QPixmap`.

```
Window::Window(QWidget *parent): QDialog(parent)
{
    // Widgets
    browserButton = new QPushButton(tr("Open"));
       imageLabel = new QLabel;

    imageLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);
    imageLabel->setScaledContents(true);


    // Connect Actions
    connect(browserButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(browserClicked()));

    // Layouts
    QVBoxLayout *topLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    topLayout->addWidget(imageLabel);
    topLayout->addWidget(browserButton);

    // Main Layout
    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->addLayout(topLayout);
    setLayout(mainLayout);
    setWindowTitle("Image Browser");
}
```

This is the button

```
void Window::browserClicked()
{
    // Get file name as QString 
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                                                    tr("Open Image"),
                                                    NULL,
                                                    tr("Image Files (*.png *.jpeg *.jpg *.bmp)"));

    // Read file name as String not QString and store the image           
    m_original_CVimg = cv::imread(fileName.toStdString());

    imageLabel->setPixmap(this->cvMatToQPixmap(m_original_CVimg));

}
```

I want to resize the image's size every time the user changes the size of the window. If I expand the window, the image also is expanded but the problem if I shrink the window, the size of the window is restricted to the size of the image. Any suggestions

Comment: Why you are not using QLayout?

Comment: @reggie_jimac, actually I'm following a book. Until now, I'm not expert but I can do simple GUIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a gander at [QResizeEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qresizeevent.html).